# data types error in Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

I was working on a project for a teacher when I encountered this error:

> two or more data type in declaration of `timer16_Sequence_t`

It happened on this piece of code:

```
typedef enum { _timer1, _Nbr_16timers } timer16_Sequence_t ;
```

I know this error is normally caused when forgetting the semicolon, but can it also have another cause? The same piece of code works fine when I don't use a custom library, but when I do this error pops up, and I can't figure out why. The language I use to program this is Arduino C.

Comment: Can you explain specifically what you mean by "when I don't use a custom library"?

Comment: @GregHewgill The library I am using is a pre made library for the control of servo's. Because there is a pre made library I can test that separately (which does what it should do, control servo's), but when I add my custom library to the project the pre made one seems to give this error, and only if the custom library is above the pre made library. When I switch them i get a whole different set of errors, which is always more then one...

Comment: Well, I think your suspicion is correct. Your header file probably has a missing something (perhaps a semicolon) near the end that isn't detected until after the end of your header file. Without posting some relevant code, it's impossible for us to guess further.

Comment: Why are you using leading underscores in your enum names?   Those are reserved for the compiler.  Perhaps that other header defines _timer1.

Comment: After about 3.5 hours searching (excluding the time I spent looking for it the past few weeks) I did indeed find a missing semicolon in my custom header file. Though it did not necessarily solved all problems it did solved this one, and now I am  singing off... Thnx GregHewgill, if you didnt told me i could be missing something in my own library i would still be searching.

Answer (score 0):

add in your library header (the .h file)

```
//add below these lines:
#ifndef x
#define x
//this
#include <Arduino.h>
```